# Let $u$ and $v$ be distinct vectors of a vector space $V$. Show that if {$u$,$v$} is a basis for $V$ and $a$ and $b$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u$ and $v$ be distinct vectors of a vector space $V$. Show that if {$u$,$v$} is a basis for $V$ and $a$ and $b$ are nonzero scalars, then both $\{u+v,au\}$ and $\{au,bv\}$ are also bases for $V.$

My proof:

Since $\{u,v\}$ is a basis, we can find $x \in V$ such that $x=x_1 u+x_2v$ for scalars $x_1=x_2=0.$

Here I only show the $\{au,bv\}.$ Since $\{u,,v\}$ are bases , we have $x=x_1u+x_2v=(\frac{x_1}{a})au+(\frac{x_2}{b})bv.$ Since we can write $\{au,bv\}$ in a linear span of $x$, they are bases.

Are there some suggestions, or is there a better way of proving?

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $V$ is two dimensional because there is one basis with two elements. Hence it is enough to show that the given sets of vectors are linearly independent. Can you show this?

Comment: I don't quite get it on the instant on the steps, can you be more specific?

Comment: You proved that $(au,bv)$ spans $V$. But that is not the definition of a basis. You also have to prove that $au$ and $bv$ are independent. Once you prove that the gives pairs of vectors are independent it would follow that they form bases because of the dimensiton argument I mentioned. @Beacon